# Is there a way to convert a PDF File to a Crystal reports file?

Tags: pdf, rpt

I am trying to convert a pdf file to a crystal report file, is that even possible?  IS there a software tool out there that does that?

I have looked on-line but can't find anything

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. 
But given that the question is a bit odd (Crystal needs a data source), perhaps what you are after is embedding a PDF form outline in Crystal.
That can be done by inserting the PDF (or an image of the form) in the page header and taking advantage of the 'Uderlay Following Sections' option. This would make the form outline act as the background for the rest of the report, allowing you to position dynamic content on top of that image.